# Getting strange ip from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server, ip

When we send out our newsletter we are tracking the clicks.
Now we are getting some really strange results...

4 different Swedish companies uses the same IP which is `4.79.123.2`(72317697). This IP is an American IP and is not usable.

Then we have 4 MORE different Swedish companies which uses `4.79.123.2` (72317698 notices the last number here).
And then we have yet 3 different companies which uses `4.79.123.3`(72317699).

I am storing the short IPs in a mysql column with int(4) unsigned.
I am converting the ips with `sprintf("%u\n", ip2long($ip))`.

I even asked my hosting company for the access log and it shows me the same IPs as above. So `$_SERVER["remote_addr"]` is working.

Do you guys have any idea to what is going on?
I and the company I work for is placed in Sweden and the companies we email is also Swedish.

Comment: Perhaps they're using an aggregator?

Comment: Hi Jay. Well I think it is very strange, everything about this.
This is the useragent they all uses

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

But how could they come from the same IP? An IP which is not even usable?

Could it perhaps be some antivirus/firewall scanner which have "clicked" on the links and its the AV/Firewall robot we see in our logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This IP is a public IP, so you logged the IP of the server all the companies went through. The companies have all different IPs and sending their "click" into the US where they all go through one hub (big server center where all the traffic goes through) witch is the one with your public IP. The traffic from europe in general is routed through many points until they reach the US so it can happen that some traffic goes past the same servers.

**Edit:**
After a quick research I found that the ip belongs to [Level 3 communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_3_Communications) which is the owner of a [tier 1 network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier_1_network) and provides fibre-optic access (I think they need pretty fast switches and routers for this). So it could be possible that it is actually faster to route your traffic all the way through the US then to keep it in sweden...

**Edit 2:**
It's a VPN. The companies probably use the same provider for their VPN solution so the traffic is routed through the US..

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This does sound reasonable but the thing is that we are a Swedish company. It sounds strange that another Swedish company travels from its computer to USA, then back to Sweden and lands on our site...

Comment: Okay, that´s weird, but indeed not impossible. So I guess your webserver is hosted in sweden too? Then it could still be that you use some sort of analytics or programs (maybe by google?) which need to route their traffic through the US servers? The only other way I could figure is that it´s faster to go through the US then through sweden, but I highly doubt that.

Comment: Thank you so much creyD! I marked your answer as valid! Do you have any recommendations on how to identify when a company comes from any of theses VPNs/strange ips and when it comes from a non-vpn/normal ip?

Comment: I guess not really, sorry. Those VPN IPs are "normal" like the other ones. I guess you could differenciate between private people and companies (as most companies use one static ip/ privates use dynamic ips) but VPN uses one static IP too, so...